# Python type hint for Sized, Iterable and Container

Tags: python-3.x, type-hinting

What type hint should I use in Python 3 to describe an argument that I will use in these 3 ways:

- `if len(arg):` ...
- `for item in arg:` ...
- `if item in arg:` ...

Comment: I've asked myself this question several times and forgot, so let's save the answer here for others as well.

Comment: Appreciate it, this post is now the second result when googling for "python type hint container" =)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You may use `collections.abc.Collection`

```py
from collections.abc import Collection

def fn(arg: Collection[int]):
    pass
```

Comment: The documentation: https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html#typing.Collection https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.abc.html#collections.abc.Collection --- Note: Since Python 3.9 you should use `collections.abc.Collection` instead of the other one from `typing`. To use the new code in older Python versions do `from __future__ import annotations`